# connect to another computer in adhoc network with RMI

Tags: java, netbeans, rmi, adhoc

I have created a simple program , that two computers connect together. I have tested on same computer, no problem.

but When I create ad-hoc network (in Windows 8 for server  and 7 for client).

One computer is a server, it run successfully
but in client i received this error :

> exception in thread main java.rmi. connectioexception : exception creating connecting to java.net.socketexceptionn: network is unreachable connect

please help me :)

Comment: no ping run successfully

Comment: Then, you need to show the code, how you're connecting the 2 machines, and how you're `ping`ing the server from the client. Provide an MCVE code.

Answer (score 0):

The network condition needs to be the same when you execute the client as it was when the server was started: specifically, the server must still have the same IP address, which must still be reachable from the client. RMI does not work with dynamic networks.

Comment: no ip server is 192.168.1.1 and ip client is 192.168.1.2 and ping in dos run successfully

Comment: And what is the address that appears in the exception message?